# Drush command not found after Drush completely installed

Tags: drush

I installed Drush 8 with composer.

```
composer require drush/drush:~8
```

Unfortunately, error **drush command not found** after Drush completely installed.

Why's the drush command can't be use?

[image]

**Installing Drush for Drupal 8 with Composer**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqY_XsCTmAc

Comment: Assuming your php is 5.4.5 or grater, I wonder if [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oKUL9.jpg) "Build Failing" has something to do with your problem.

Comment: @NoSssweat Thanks. How do I remove it? Is that remove the composer.json?

Comment: [How to uninstall drush via composer?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135599/how-to-uninstall-drush-via-composer)

Comment: Then try installing Drush 9 master/dev.

Comment: `composer global require drush/drush:dev-master`

Comment: I had tried install Drush 9 dev, Problem, Installation request for drush/drush dev-master -> satisfiable by drush/drush[dev-master]. How do I set the minimum stability?

Comment: You have PHP 5.5 or higher?  you can check by typing `php -v`

Comment: Ok turns out that "Build Failing" had nothing to do with your problem. see [Should I install Drush 8 or Drush 9 for Drupal 8?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206609/should-i-install-drush-8-or-drush-9-for-drupal-8)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Once you have installed Drush, you need to ensure that you ~/vendor/bin directory is in your $PATH, as [explained in the installation instructions](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install-alternative/) **(Note: this link no longer works)**

Add `export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"` to your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc, and then run `source ~/.bash_profile` (or ~/.bashrc).

I would recommend against installing Drush 9 via `composer require` at this time. Sticking with Drush 8 is probably best; if you want to use Drush 9, use a simpler installation method, such downloading the .phar, or clone the repository and run `composer install` in the directory Drush was cloned to.

Comment: `I would recommend against installing Drush 9 via composer require at this time.` Thanks for the info!

Comment: What is the reason to against installing Drush 9 via `composer require` ?

Comment: The non-stable version of Drush requires some non-stable versions of its dependencies. This can cause some complications, depending on what you are doing. Generally you get around this by setting your minimum stability, but it's simpler to just install via another method. As an aside, if you are inclined to use `composer global require` for anything, please see https://github.com/consolidation-org/cgr

Comment: @JimmyKo The reason that a global Drush isn't recommended  is that with Drush 9+, best practices recommend Drush to be installed as a dependency for Drupal. This prevents issues with a Drush version mismatch, for example.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, ` ~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` might have been edited. Back it up and find a default one.

Comment: For non-interactive connections (ie, when using drush ssh alias), [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940533/how-do-i-set-path-such-that-ssh-userhost-command-works/941995#941995) may help if the other answers don't. On MacOS Catalina, I had to add a `zshenv` file (without a leading dot) with my desired export paths inside /etc (not my home directory). Bear in mind, this is for non-interactive shell connections (that don't source your personal .zshrc/.bashrc files).

Answer (score 21):

Using ssh on my server host I did add drush to my path following composer instructions: Add

```
    export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

to your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc, and then run source ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.bashrc)

However, I got this running

```
    drush status
    -bash: drush: command not found

    which composer
    /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer

    which drush   
    /usr/bin/which: no drush in (/home/mth/.composer/vendor/bin:/home/mth/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/home/mth/bin:/home/mth/bin)
```

Using my cPanel file manager, I found I couldn't see the hidden composer folder, though I saw other hidden folders and files (dot prefix). It turns out composer was within the .config folder. I added the new folder to my $PATH and bingo!

```
    export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Hours! Moral? Verify composer location.

Comment: Thanks for the `code` export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" `code`. It help me solve my problem.

Comment: OMG...I spent 2 hours trying to figure this out because of this. I can't believe how blind I was...but THANK YOU.

Comment: helped on shared server

Answer (score 4):

Anyone on Ubuntu 20.04?

I noticed composer installs not in ~/.composer/vendor/bin, but ~/.config/composer..

Super weird, since nobody has mentioned that (important) fact.

I am sure with the proper path sourced, it will work now..

I changed my $PATH in ~/.bashrc to ~/.config/composer/vendor/bin like this:
`export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

..and it works!

Comment: Yeah the path should be `export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin/:$PATH"
`, I found it so late :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that `drush` is located within your environmental `PATH` variable, or you can specify installation folder by setting `COMPOSER_BIN_DIR`, e.g.:

> `sudo COMPOSER_HOME=/var/lib/composer COMPOSER_BIN_DIR=/usr/local/bin COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR=/var/lib/composer/vendor composer require drush/drush:~8`

Or it's much easier to install it via Phar, e.g. on Linux:

```
sudo install <(curl http://files.drush.org/drush.phar) /usr/local/bin/drush
```

On OS X, try: `brew install drush`.

Answer (score 1):

Now, although my issues were with a Composer Scaffold install for Drupal 8 which needs Drush (in this case v.9) installed as a dependency, I too was having similar issues. Even though a global Drush is no longer recommended, due to dependency issues, it's very convenient to call upon Drush from anywhere.

What I would recommend installing is [Drush Launcher](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher), which will give you the option of calling Drush from anywhere, even if you are running different projects using different versions of Drush. I have it running both locally and on my Web servers, and it's running fine there. It fixed my issues of seeing `drush: command not found`, even when I had projects where Composer had correctly installed Drush.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to run `vendor/bin/drush <command>`.